# General relativity: For massless particles, is the momentum and velocity 4-vectors equal?

Tags: general-relativity, photons, momentum, velocity, geodesics

I am following Carroll's GR book. He explain that it is convention to parameterize geodesics of photons by a parameter $\lambda$ such that 
$$p^\mu ~=~ \frac{d x^{\mu}}{d \lambda}.\tag{3.62}$$ 
But this is the definition of 4-velocity for a massive particle in the case of $\lambda=\tau$ equal to proper time. My question then, is $$u^\mu = p^\mu$$ for all massless particles? I ask because it's well-known that proper time $\tau$ freezes for massless particles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. How should we define momentum  of a massless point particle? It seems most systematic to use the Lagrangian formalism. The Lagrangian of a massive or massless point particle is$^1$ 
   $$ L~=~\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2e}-\frac{m^2e}{2}, \qquad \dot{x}^2~:=~g_{\mu\nu}(x)~ \dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}~<~0,  \qquad  \dot{x}^{\mu}~:=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda} ,\tag{1}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107921/2451), [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137857/2451) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) Phys.SE posts. We now restrict to the massless case
   $$ m~=~0. \tag{2}$$
2. In eq. (1) $\lambda$ is a worldline (WL) parameter, and $e>0$ is a WL einbein field introduced to make the action 
   $$S[x,e]~=~ \int\! \mathrm{d}\lambda ~L\tag{3}$$ 
   gauge invariant under WL reparamerizations 
   $$  \lambda\longrightarrow \lambda^{\prime}~=~f(\lambda).\tag{4} $$
   In more detail the WL einbein field $e$ transforms as a WL co-vector/one-form, 
   $$ e~\mathrm{d}\lambda~=~e^{\prime}~ \mathrm{d}\lambda^{\prime}.\tag{5} $$
3. We can now address OP's question. The Lagrangian $4$-momentum$^2$ is defined in the standard way:
   $$ p_{\mu}~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ \frac{1}{e}g_{\mu\nu}(x)~\dot{x}^{\nu}.\tag{6}$$
4. Carroll's eq. (3.62), which in our notation reads$^3$ 
   $$p^{\mu}~=~\dot{x}^{\mu}, \tag{7}$$ 
   is eq. (6) in the gauge $e=1$, cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130867/2451) Phys.SE post.

--

$^1$ In this answer we put the speed of light $c=1$ to one and use the sign convention $(−,+,+,+)$.

$^2$ It is fun to check that in the massive case the Lagrangian momentum (6) becomes the standard [$4$-momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum)
$$ p^{\mu}~\approx~\frac{m\dot{x}^{\mu}}{\sqrt{-\dot{x}^2}}\tag{8}$$
in the static gauge $\lambda=x^0$ in Minkowski space. [Here the $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eom.]

$^3$ Note that the notion of [$4$-velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity)
$$ u^{\mu}~:=~\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau} \tag{9} $$
is not defined for massless particles. Here $\tau$ denotes [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time), which doesn't change for a massless particle. So OP's equation $p^{\mu}=u^{\mu}$ does not make sense if $u^{\mu}$ is supposed to be the conventional 4-velocity.

Answer (score 0):

So a massless particle obeys $E = pc$ which is a special case of the relativistic equation $$(m c)^2 = p^\mu p_\mu = (E/c)^2 - |\vec p|^2,$$ when $m=0$. Indeed when we have a massive particle we have $\lambda = \tau/m$, but with a massless particle neither of these are defined: massleses particles do not have mass and do not experience time. Nevertheless you can imagine choosing someone who sees the particle moving at speed $c$ and using their local coordinate of time $t$, describing it as a 4-position path $x^\mu(t) = (ct, \vec x_0 +\vec v~t).$ Not everyone agrees on the $t$-derivative of this because not everyone agrees on $t$, but indeed there is a frame-dependent proportionality constant to take this to the 4-momentum and we can combine that with  $t$ into $\lambda$. So the problem is that there is no $u^\mu$ for massless particles, because there is no $\tau$ for massless particles, but we still have  $p^\mu$ and  $\lambda$ just fine.

Comment: But in special relativity we have $u^\mu$ for massless particles. In this case, is $p^\mu = u^\mu$?

Comment: No. There is no $u^\mu$ for massless particles in special relativity. There just isn't. If someone told you that there is, they were telling you a half-truth at best. There is a path, $\{\forall s: x^\mu(s)\},$ which everyone agrees on (subject to reparameterizations of $s$ and Poincaré transforms of the 4-vectors in the set, of course), but the tangent vectors to this path are all null vectors. $u^\mu(s)$ is defined as the tangent vector corresponding to $x^\mu(s)$ normalized so that $u^\mu~u_\mu = c^2$ (in the $(+ - - -)$ metric) and you simply cannot normalize null vectors this way.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent vector (field) of a world line is not well-defined since the tangent vector is the derivative *with respect to a parameter*. Hence the tangent vector is parametrization-dependent. However, whether the tangent is timelike or lightlike (null) is invariant. For massive particles, $ds^2 > 0$, so the space time interval integrated along the curve can be used as a parameter. This is the the *proper time*, and we get the 4-velocity as $u^\mu = dx^\mu/d\tau$.

For massless particles, $ds^2 = 0$ and there is no notion of proper time. However, it can be shown that any curve can be given an affine parameter $\lambda$ such that the geodesic equation expressed in $\lambda$-derivatives takes a particular form. All such parameters are related affinely $$\lambda_1 = k\lambda_2 + m$$
where $k,m$ are constants. 
This is enough freedom to choose $\lambda$ such that Carroll's condition holds.

(The 4-momentum can be defined in a parametrization-invariant way.)

Comment: So is $u^\mu = p^\mu$ or not?

Comment: $u^\mu$ cannot be defined for light-like worldlines