# Can change in mass of charge, change value of charge (according to theory of relativity)?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, electrostatics, mass, charge

We all know that for presence of charge it is necessary of presence of mass. If mass changes, in some conditions, according to theory of relativity, then charge should also change.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As per https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/715865/ charged objects can theoretically be made without mass

Answer (score 1):

> We all know that for presence of charge it is necessary of presence of mass

The word "mass" in this statement refers to the invariant mass. That is the usual meaning of "mass" as used by modern practicing physicists.

> If mass changes, in some conditions, according to theory of relativity

The invariant mass is the same in all reference frames. That is what invariant means.