# Can a massless charged particles moving with the speed of light exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, charge, speed-of-light

Consider a massless charged particle uniformly moving in vacuum at a constant velocity with the speed of light. The usual expressions for electric and magnetic fields give weird results in this case. Take electric field as an example — it would show that the field “collapses” into a plane perpendicular to the line of motion.

Usually “infinities” indicate a problem in the theory. So I wonder if such particles can exist theoretically? If I am not mistaken, there are no empirically known examples.

Is it the result of the assumption that the particle is truly a point? Maybe there are some quantum effects to “rescue”?

Comment: Does the charged particle have mass?

Comment: @JonCuster no, a massless charged particle

Comment: There are no known massless charged particles.

Comment: @JonCuster right, I mentioned it in my question. My question is can they exist theoretically? If yes then what EM they produce?

Comment: I edited my question to add a note about masslessness of the particle

Comment: Yes https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/715865/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this proof that massless objects cannot be charged?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/715865/)

Comment: @jensenpaull I'm sorry, the argument there is wrong because it's based on an incorrect assumption that $F=ma$ in relativistic case